# Cheerio JS Can I check if an attribute is included in an element I already selected in cheerio JS

Tags: node.js, cheerio

I am wondering if I can check if an element has a certain attribute after locating it, and if it has that attribute, avoid it and get a new one.

Here is the html I am using:

```
<option
              
              
              value="19438389624960">
                1
            </option>
          
            <option
              
              disabled="disabled"
              value="19438389657728">
                2
            </option>
          
            <option
              
              
              value="19438389690496">
                3
            </option>
          
            <option
              
              disabled="disabled"
              value="19438389723264">
                4
            </option>
```

As you can see, 2 of the 4 options have a `disabled="disabled"` attribute that I want to avoid, is there anyway I can do that ?

I currently have this code that chooses a random value out of all the options:

```
var list = [];
                $('select[name=id]').find('option').each(function (index, element) {
                    list.push($(element).attr('value'));
                });

                const randomVar = list[Math.random() * list.length | 0]

                variant = randomVar
```

But this code still will choose the ones that have the `disabled="disabled"` attr

Comment: You can try `$('select[name=id]').find('option[disabled!="disabled"]')` and see if Cheerio supports that jQuery extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
$('select[name=id]').find('option[disabled!="disabled"]').each(...)
```

to skip the options that have `disabled=disabled`.  Then, you will be picking a random one from only the non-disabled items.  Since cheerio uses the same selector engine as jQuery, you can find this kind of stuff in the relevant page of the [jQuery doc](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector/).

Answer (score 1):

`:not` is a regular css pseudo, which means it works everywhere:

```
$('option:not([disabled="disabled"])')
```

or probably just:

```
$('option:not([disabled])')
```